# From intern to permanent

Tags: salary

I have been working as an intern for 3 month and my internship ended after 3 months. I worked for the company for 2 more months without a contract and still got payed the same package.

Now I am working for them with a full time contract but I am still getting paid the same amount as an intern with no benefits.

Is it the right thing that the company is doing? Will it be wrong if I ask for increase? And how do I do that?

Comment: The said they will increase it when they closing for the year... nothing has happened.I signed it because ofthe promise and again if i didnt she sign it who was going to pay bills... sometimes being unemployed make us settle for less.

Comment: Was that written in writing? Unless you have it written down that they would increase your pay when closing the year, you shouldn't have signed. Trying to prove something verbal happened isn't as easy as if it was written down

Comment: Not sure on why the close votes, I feel this is a valid question. Could anyone point out why it should be closed? I don't believe the OP is asking for advice on what to do, but more checking if they are being screwed over. This could be possibly closed under the legal aspect, however I feel it's far enough away to count as a suitable question

Answer (score 2):

> now I am working for them with full time contract but i am still getting payed the same amount as an intern with no benefits? Is it the right thing that the company is doing?

What does the contract say about pay and benefits? If they are giving you what they promised, and it meets the legal requirements in your jurisdiction, then the company isn't doing anything wrong.

> Will it be wrong if I ask for increase?

No.

> And how do i do it?

Just ask for a raise. Sometimes people bring some documentation about average pay and industry norms, etc, to make their case but I don't think that really helps. Usually the employer just pays what they think it would cost to replace you and no more.